# Autocomplete and suggester combination for Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to make an elastic search autocomplete and suggest. I will be used for searching for company names. It works OK but the suggest is only performed on the beginning to the company name. ( E.G. Sports Company inc. will only be shown for searches starting like 'sports' and not 'company'). I have read theat the autocomplete is for prefixes, but I want it to work on all words.

My question is how to go about using either; suggest, autocomplete, filters, tokenizers to get get it working. I understand that they all have influences on results, but what has more and what has less. I find the docs quite hard to understand.

I also, would like to know the best way to go about searching all words in a company name vs prefix only.

Settings:

```
{
    "settings" : {
        "analysis" : {
            "char_filter" : {
                "-_to_space" : {
                    "type" : "mapping",
                    "mappings" : [ "-=>", ".=>" ]
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "company_stopwords" : {
                    "type" : "stop",
                    "stopwords" : [ "the", "a", "." ]
                }
            },
            "analyzer" : {
                "company_analyzer" : {
                    "type" : "custom",
                    "char_filter" : [ "html_strip", "-_to_space" ],
                    "tokenizer" : "standard",
                    "filter" : [ "lowercase", "company_stopwords" ]
                }
            }
        },
        "number_of_replicas" : 0
    }
}
```

Mappings

```
{
    "properties" : {
        "name" : { 
            "type" : "string"
        },
        "suggest" : {
            "type" : "completion",
            "index_analyzer" : "simple",
            "search_analyzer" : "company_analyzer",
            "payloads" : "true"
        },
        "activated" : { 
            "type" : "integer"
        },
        "banned" : { 
            "type" : "integer"
        },
        "disabled" : { 
            "type" : "integer"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you ever figure this out?  i'm also trying to use completion suggestion from parts other than only the start of the word.

Comment: [http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/you-complete-me/] it looks like the best you can do is define multiple suggestion inputs when you're indexing the documents.  Or build your own suggester.  I found this page helpful [http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/What-are-good-combinations-of-search-analyzer-index-analyzer-and-query-for-implementing-an-effective-td4048638.html]